# OpenCL Sub Buffer Host pointer

Tags: opencl

I have created a buffer with attributes CL_MEM_READ_WRITE and CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR. I have enqueued this buffer to GPU kernels. GPU kernels process the input given and fill these buffers. During this process CPU is made to wait. I have modified this design by partitioning the buffer in to three uniform sections using sub-buffers. Now GPU after filling one sub-buffer, CPU can start processing. This reduces CPU wait to one sub-buffer as opposed to one full frame processing.

The problem i am facing is, the mapped pointer (cpu side pointers) of sub-buffers and buffer are strange. The map pointer of the first sub-buffer and buffer are same. This is alright. But the map pointer of second sub-buffer is not equal to the map pointer of buffer + offset of second sub-buffer. I tried this on integrated GPU models (Intel HD graphics 4000). It was working fine. But when i run this on dedicated graphics card devices (nvidia zotac) i am facing this problem. Have you encountered such a scenario before. Can you provide some pointers to where to look to fix this problem.

```
typedef struct opencl_buffer {
  cl_mem opencl_mem;
  void *mapped_pointer;
  int size;
}opencl_buffer;

// alloc gpu output buffers
opencl->opencl_mem = clCreateBuffer(
    opencl->context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR,
    3 * alloc_size, NULL, &status);
if (status != CL_SUCCESS)
  goto fail;

// create output sub buffers
for (sub_idx = 0; sub_idx < 3; ++sub_idx) {
  cl_buffer_region sf_region;
  SubFrameInfo subframe;

  sf_region.origin = alloc_size * sub_idx;
  sf_region.size = alloc_size;
  opencl->gpu_output_sub_buf[sub_idx].size = sf_region.size;
  opencl->gpu_output_sub_buf[sub_idx].opencl_mem =
      clCreateSubBuffer(opencl->opencl_mem,
                        CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,
                        CL_BUFFER_CREATE_TYPE_REGION,
                        &sf_region, &status);
  if (status != CL_SUCCESS)
    goto fail;
}
```

Now, when i map gpu_output_sub_buf[0].opencl_mem and gpu_output_sub_buf[1].opencl_mem, the difference between CPU side pointers is  expected to be alloc_size (assume char pointers). This happens to be the case in Intel HD graphics. But Nvidia platform is providing a different result.

Comment: What do you mean by _map pointer of second sub-buffer_? Could you please add some code to your question showing the call of `clCreateBuffer` (C API) or construction of `cl::Buffer` (C++ API)?

Comment: Your added code snippet misses the assignment of `mapped_pointer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specification-based reason a mapped sub-buffer should be at an address that is a known offset from the mapped main buffer (or mapped sub-buffer that aligns with same). Mapping only creates a range of host memory that you can use, and then you unmap to get it back on the device. It doesn't have to even be at the same address each time.

Of course OpenCL 2.0 SVM changes all this, but you didn't say you're using SVM, and NVIDIA doesn't support OpenCL 2.0 today anyway.